# How to sort List1 (int) so corresponding List2 (string) be also sorted?

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner and I need help!!!

I have 2 lists with the same number of items:

```
int Score  string Name
  523         toto
  125         gaga
  428         zaza
  625         dudu
```

I want to sort Score in descending order with corresponding Name :

```
int Score  string Name
  625         dudu
  523         toto
  428         zaza
  125         gaga
```

What is the simplest & shortest code solution? (Linq??)
How to print the result?

Thanks!!!

I know how to do it with arrays:
... but with Lists, it seems more complicated.

Sort(Score,Name) + Reverse(Score) + Reverse (Name)

Comment: You should create a class with properties `Score` and `Name` and create a list of that class and then sort that list using linq

Comment: Simply use any sorting algorithm on your first list but handle both list within that algorithm, or use [SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) making its keys the first list and its values the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them all into a anonymous class (imho no need to create a full class spec just for that one example), sort by `num` descending, print `num` and `names`.

Full example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var nums = new List<int>{523, 125, 428, 625};
        var names = new List<string>{"toto", "gaga", "zaza", "dudu"};

        // create combined tuples using Select with index, using _Zip_is more elegant
        var combined = nums.Select((n, i) => new
        {
            num = n, name = names[i]
        }

        ).OrderByDescending(tup => tup.num);

        foreach (var c in combined)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", c.num, c.name));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
625 dudu
523 toto
428 zaza
125 gaga
```

Readup:

- [Basic linq query operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations) (the formal way)
- [Enumerable.Select using Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: If you want to give OP some reading; you might want to start with OOP ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Combine them into a class

```
public class Score
{
    public int Value { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    public Score(int value, string name) => (Value, Name) = (value, name);
}
```

Then sorting will work naturally

```
var scores = new List<Score> {}; // create list

var orderedScores = scores.OrderByDescending(score => score.Value).ToList();
```

You can create list of scores from your two lists by using `.Zip` extension method

```
var scores = scoreValues.Zip(scoreNames, (value, name) => new Score(value, name)).ToList();
```